# custom aggregators with client_states as states

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I want to create a custom aggregator where the state is the unique client state of each client. To initialize I can define client states as usual, and then use `federated_collect` to place `@SERVER` placement since thats what `initialize_fn()` wants. I can also do the same for creating `new_state` in the `next_fn()`. The problem is once I don't know how I can "broadcast" these states back into clients. Normally `federated_broadcast` takes say `A@SERVER` and then makes copies of it equal to number of clients. so for two clients it would be `{A}@CLIENTS` lets say `(A A)`. What I want is to have `AB@SERVER` turning into `(A B)`.

I am currently defining client states outside the aggregation process, and then passing these in `run_one_round` of iterative process. use `federated_collect` to collect these states from measurements of aggregator, and then unstack it outside. So from the outside of the federated computations it looks like

```py
    server_state, train_metrics , client_states, aggregation_state = iterative_process.next(
                    server_state, sampled_train_data, client_states, aggregation_state)
    client_states = [x for x in client_states]
```

In TFF

```py
    output = aggregation_process.next(aggregation_state, client_outputs.weights_delta, client_states)
    new_aggregation_state = output.state
    round_model_delta = output.result
    new_client_states = output.measurements
```

in aggregator

```py
        measurements = tff.federated_collect(new_client_states)
        return tff.templates.MeasuredProcessOutput(
            state=new_state, result= round_model_delta, measurements=measurements)
```

But I am trying to define and handle these client states completely inside the aggregator so that I can plug this aggregator into `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process` like

```py
    iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
        model_fn,
        client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
        server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
        model_update_aggregation_factory=my_aggregation_factory)
```

Is that possible? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

`tff.federated_collect` is likely not the desired tool in this situation, and it will be removed in future versions of TFF (see commit [#030a406](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/commit/030a406d3d69f1b741b5129c5d3c91c10bfe9859#diff-0603ad390ce2006e83987028a4cedc2760b1d0d03b2a75eadda204672662cc87)).

Alternatively, A `tff.federated_computation` can both take `@CLIENTS` parameters as input, and **return `@CLIENT` placed values as output**. Instead of collecting all the values on the server first (implying that the system is communicating the states); it maybe best to leave the values on the clients.

When executing TFF in a simulation environment (e.g. invoking a `tff.Computation` in a Colab notebook) a `T@CLIENT` placed value will be returned as a `list` of `T` objects; one for each client. This can later be used as a parameter to future `tff.Computation` invocation.

Example:

```py
@tff.tf_computation(tf.int32)
def sqrt(value):
  return tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(value, tf.float32))

@tff.federated_computation(tff.types.at_clients(tf.int32))
def federated_sqrt(values):
  return tff.federated_map(sqrt, values)

client_values = [1,2,3,4]
federated_sqrt(client_values)
>>> [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.4142135>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.7320508>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>]
```

**Important caveat**: the order of inputs and outputs is not necessarily guaranteed to be the same. An example of how to index and track states across invocations can be found in the [`tensorflow_federated/python/examples/stateful_clients/`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/main/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/stateful_clients) directory inside the repository.

Comment: thanks for your answer and edit. If I am understanding you correctly I have already done that. I implemented a paper by using the stateful clients example you linked . I initiated the client states in main and get client states back from client update by using ClientOutput. I have used CLIENTS -> CLIENTS computations in run_one_round as well. But now i want to move all of this into a self contained custom aggregation factory so i can simply plug this into build_federated_averaging_process. But i dont know how to evade declaring these client states in main.

Comment: I also implemented a custom aggregation with client states coming from main where they were initialized separate from the aggregation initialization. But this prevents me from plugging this aggregation into build_federated_averaging_process. So my point is i know i can have federated_computations with CLIENTS -> CLIENTS signature and client states as input. I just dont know where else i can get them apart from main. also thanks for caveat. i wasnt aware. i just run 200 rounds with sample data-model and its always in order. is this related to single/multi gpu use?

Comment: Unfortunately `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process` is designed in such a way that it's _very_ difficult to add a notion of client state. I'd recommend creating a new "client-stateful FedAvg" (forking) algorithm, rather than trying to contort the naïve design that is tailored for [McMahan et al., 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629). Note that `tff.aggregators.AggregationFactory` creates [`tff.templates.AggregationProcess`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/templates/AggregationProcess) which requires all state be at the server.

Comment: Re the caveat: Its quite possible that the TFF runtime currently returns the clients in the same order for some configurations, but this is not part of the API contract; rather a detail of the particular implementation. It may not be true in future versions, but sounds like you can collect useful data at the moment!

Comment: thank you for your insightful answers. is it possible to explain what you mean by "a new "client-stateful FedAvg" (forking) algorithm". i am confused about the exact meaning of "client-stateful FedAvg" (forking)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, what I'd like to suggest is writing a new Python method that constructs a `tff.templates.IterativeProcess`, instead of trying to find a way to re-use `build_federated_averaging_process` with a new set of parameters. I think it will be very difficult to re-use `build_federated_averaging_process` since it include many assumptions that any "state" only resides on the server.